# Incorrect syntax near 'nvarchar'. I get this error whenever trying to update a field on a database table using a grid view

Tags: sql, asp.net

This is my ASP.net code the query gets all details from the customer table and then in the grid view the user is allowed to edit the fields. Whenever i click update it throws that error then. When researching the problem i seen alot of people where saying about using spaces and [] but i tried the code with no spaces and no brackets but still get the same error. I also tried adding a @ for the parameters in the gridview Please Help.

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConflictDetection="CompareAllValues" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:BookConnString %>" DeleteCommand="DELETE FROM Customer WHERE Email = @original_Email AND (([First Name] = @original_First_Name) OR ([First Name] IS NULL AND @original_First_Name IS NULL)) AND (([Surname] = @original_Surname) OR ([Surname] IS NULL AND @original_Surname IS NULL)) AND (([Address] = @original_Address) OR ([Address] IS NULL AND @original_Address IS NULL)) AND (([Postcode] = @original_Postcode) OR ([Postcode] IS NULL AND @original_Postcode IS NULL)) AND (([Gender] = @original_Gender) OR ([Gender] IS NULL AND @original_Gender IS NULL))" InsertCommand="INSERT INTO Customer ([Email], [First Name], [Surname], [Address], [Postcode], [Gender]) VALUES (@Email, @First_Name, @Surname, @Address, @Postcode, @Gender)" OldValuesParameterFormatString="original_{0}" SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM Customer" UpdateCommand="UPDATE Customer SET [First Name] = @First_Name, [Surname] = @Surname, [Address] = @Address, [Postcode] = @Postcode, [Gender] = @Gender WHERE [Email] = @original_Email AND (([First Name] = @original_First_Name) OR ([First Name] IS NULL AND @original_First_Name IS NULL)) AND (([Surname] = @original_Surname) OR ([Surname] IS NULL AND @original_Surname IS NULL)) AND (([Address] = @original_Address) OR ([Address] IS NULL AND @original_Address IS NULL)) AND (([Postcode] = @original_Postcode) OR ([Postcode] IS NULL AND @original_Postcode IS NULL)) AND (([Gender] = @original_Gender) OR ([Gender] IS NULL AND @original_Gender IS NULL))">
        <DeleteParameters>
            <asp:Parameter Name="original_Email" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="original_First_Name" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="original_Surname" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="original_Address" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="original_Postcode" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="original_Gender" Type="String" />
        </DeleteParameters>
        <InsertParameters>
            <asp:Parameter Name="Email" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="First_Name" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="Surname" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="Address" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="Postcode" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="Gender" Type="String" />
        </InsertParameters>
        <UpdateParameters>
            <asp:Parameter Name="First_Name" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="Surname" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="Address" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="Postcode" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="Gender" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="original_Email" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="original_First_Name" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="original_Surname" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="original_Address" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="original_Postcode" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="original_Gender" Type="String" />
        </UpdateParameters>
    </asp:SqlDataSource>
</p>
<p class="auto-style4">
    <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="Email" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1">
        <Columns>
            <asp:CommandField ShowEditButton="True" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Email" HeaderText="Email" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="Email" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="First Name" HeaderText="First Name" SortExpression="First Name" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Surname" HeaderText="Surname" SortExpression="Surname" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Address" HeaderText="Address" SortExpression="Address" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Postcode" HeaderText="Postcode" SortExpression="Postcode" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Gender" HeaderText="Gender" SortExpression="Gender" />
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
```

Comment: In the Bound Field collection, you have "First Name".  You tried that without spaces and still got the error?

Comment: Yeah still get the error, just tried to take the space out of datafield property and it couldnt find it in the datasource, also tried to take the space out of sort expression and the first error still comes up, also tried to put [] around them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem originated from these lines:

```
-- first problem
SELECT * FROM Customer

<%-- second problem --%>
<asp:BoundField DataField="First Name" HeaderText="First Name" SortExpression="First Name" />
```

First, by using `SELECT *` in first query makes all table columns (including `First Name` with spaces) selected, and possibly causing syntax error when binding with `BoundField`. You need to change query with alias (using `AS` keyword) for column name with spaces like this:

```
SelectCommand="SELECT [First Name] AS First_Name, Surname, Address, Postcode, Gender, Email FROM Customer"
```

Note that by using column alias, you can't use `*` anymore and need to include all column names to bind properly with GridView.

Second, the `DataField` (and `SortExpression`) accepts column name with same rule as identifier names in code behind, hence `First Name` is not accepted and need to use underscore instead:

```
<asp:BoundField DataField="First_Name" HeaderText="First Name" SortExpression="First_Name" />
```

As alternative to column alias, try to change `First Name` column as `First_Name` (or `FirstName` if Pascal case preferred) in database table, query and `DataField` name as in example below (no need to use square brackets surrounding column names):

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:BookConnString %>" 
     DeleteCommand="DELETE FROM Customer WHERE Email = @original_Email AND ((First_Name = @original_First_Name) ...)" 
     SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM Customer" 
     UpdateCommand="UPDATE Customer SET First_Name = @First_Name, Surname = @Surname, ... WHERE Email = @original_Email AND ((First_Name = @original_First_Name) OR (First_Name IS NULL ...) ...)">
     ...
 </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Similar issue:

[Incorrect syntax near nvarchar in GridView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16376186/incorrect-syntax-near-nvarchar-in-gridview)

Comment: Thanks very much this works now, from reading on the problem I knew it was something to do with the space in first name but didn't know how to change it but thanks for this. Its a really good descriptive answer.