# Incorrect syntax near 'nvarchar'. Must declare the scalar variable "@RegID"

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, visual-studio, sql-update

[image: ***ERROR MESSAGE***]

[image: UPDATE Query]
I am trying to update/edit the user details from the update query but I am getting the error Must declare a scalar Variable @RegID. I tried playing around with the query but it still comes up with the same error.

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:rm3558nConnectionString2 %>" DeleteCommand="DELETE FROM [Registration] WHERE [RegID] = @original_RegID" InsertCommand="INSERT INTO [Registration] ([First Name], [Last Name], [Email ID], [Password], [Confirm Password], [DOB], [Gender]) VALUES (@First_Name, @Last_Name, @Email_ID, @Password, @Confirm_Password, @DOB, @Gender)" SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [Registration] WHERE ([Email ID] = @Email_ID)" UpdateCommand="UPDATE [Registration] SET [First Name] = @First_Name, [Last Name] = @Last_Name, [Email ID] = @Email_ID, [Password] = @Password, [Confirm Password] = @Confirm_Password, [DOB] = @DOB, [Gender] = @Gender WHERE [RegID] = @original_RegID" OldValuesParameterFormatString="original_{0}">
                <DeleteParameters>
                    <asp:Parameter Name="original_RegID" Type="Int32" />
                </DeleteParameters>
                <InsertParameters>
                    <asp:Parameter Name="First_Name" Type="String" />
                    <asp:Parameter Name="Last_Name" Type="String" />
                    <asp:Parameter Name="Email_ID" Type="String" />
                    <asp:Parameter Name="Password" Type="String" />
                    <asp:Parameter Name="Confirm_Password" Type="String" />
                    <asp:Parameter DbType="Date" Name="DOB" />
                    <asp:Parameter Name="Gender" Type="String" />
                </InsertParameters>
                <SelectParameters>
                    <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="Namelbl" Name="Email_ID" PropertyName="Text" Type="String" />
                </SelectParameters>
                <UpdateParameters>
                    <asp:Parameter Name="First_Name" Type="String" />
                    <asp:Parameter Name="Last_Name" Type="String" />
                    <asp:Parameter Name="Email_ID" Type="String" />
                    <asp:Parameter Name="Password" Type="String" />
                    <asp:Parameter Name="Confirm_Password" Type="String" />
                    <asp:Parameter DbType="Date" Name="DOB" />
                    <asp:Parameter Name="Gender" Type="String" />
                    <asp:Parameter Name="original_RegID" Type="Int32" />
                </UpdateParameters>
            </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

**GRID VIEW**

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" BackColor="White" BorderColor="#CCCCCC" BorderStyle="None" BorderWidth="1px" CellPadding="4" DataKeyNames="RegID" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" ForeColor="Black" GridLines="Horizontal">
            <Columns>
                <asp:CommandField ShowDeleteButton="True" ShowEditButton="True" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="RegID" HeaderText="RegID" InsertVisible="False" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="RegID" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="First Name" HeaderText="First Name" SortExpression="First Name" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Last Name" HeaderText="Last Name" SortExpression="Last Name" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Email ID" HeaderText="Email ID" SortExpression="Email ID" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Password" HeaderText="Password" SortExpression="Password" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Confirm Password" HeaderText="Confirm Password" SortExpression="Confirm Password" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="DOB" HeaderText="DOB" SortExpression="DOB" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Gender" HeaderText="Gender" SortExpression="Gender" />
            </Columns>
            <FooterStyle BackColor="#CCCC99" ForeColor="Black" />
            <HeaderStyle BackColor="#333333" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
            <PagerStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="Black" HorizontalAlign="Right" />
            <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#CC3333" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
            <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#F7F7F7" />
            <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#4B4B4B" />
            <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#E5E5E5" />
            <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#242121" />
            </asp:GridView>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Incorrect syntax near 'nvarchar' must declare scalar variable near @num](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11801373/incorrect-syntax-near-nvarchar-must-declare-scalar-variable-near-num)

Comment: @Div didn't help

Comment: Your query seems runnable, have you bind the `SqlDataSource` to another control (e.g. `GridView`)? Make sure your `Bind` command doesn't contain brackets like this: `<%# Bind("[RegID]") %>`

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto I have edited and added the grid view code as well, please have a look above

Comment: Seems I found the source of your issue. Since there was fields with whitespaces on the table, `SqlDataSource` may have created table naming using underscores (e.g. `First_Name)` where `BoundField` still keeping to use whitespaces as field name. Try replacing whitespaces on table column names in both `SqlDataSource` and `BoundField` using underscores.

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto your answer makes sense and I did try it but the error remains to be the same.

Comment: I found that your problem is not truly coming from `UpdateCommand`, it is from your `SelectCommand`. `SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [Registration] WHERE ([Email ID] = @Email_ID)` returns **all** field names without using alias, and you can't have whitespaces on your column names when binding to the `GridView`. Try adding alias for every column names using underscores inside `SelectCommand` and change all `BoundField` names also with underscores.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/141486/discussion-between-rajat-and-tetsuya-yamamoto).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem occurs when `SelectCommand` output inside `SqlDataSource` using field names with whitespaces (marked with `SELECT * ...` which selects all columns without using alias), while `BoundField` inside `GridView` control doesn't accept field/column names using whitespaces.

Therefore, you need to use `SELECT` statement in `SelectCommand` mentioning all field names used for `DataField` attribute in `GridView`, and **only alias all columns that have whitespaces on them** like this:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ...
SelectCommand="SELECT [RegID], [First Name] AS First_Name, [Last Name] AS Last_Name, [Email ID] AS Email_ID, [Password], [Confirm Password] AS Confirm_Password, DOB, Gender FROM [Registration] WHERE ([Email ID] = @Email_ID)" 
...>
...
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Then in your `GridView`, declare all `DataField` field names with underscores or just remove whitespaces following convention in `SelectCommand` inside `SqlDataSource`, and use them with `SortExpression` attribute:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" BackColor="White" BorderColor="#CCCCCC" BorderStyle="None" BorderWidth="1px" CellPadding="4" DataKeyNames="RegID" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" ForeColor="Black" GridLines="Horizontal">
    <Columns>
        <asp:CommandField ShowDeleteButton="True" ShowEditButton="True" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="RegID" HeaderText="RegID" InsertVisible="False" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="RegID" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="First_Name" HeaderText="First Name" SortExpression="First_Name" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Last_Name" HeaderText="Last Name" SortExpression="Last_Name" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Email_ID" HeaderText="Email ID" SortExpression="Email_ID" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Password" HeaderText="Password" SortExpression="Password" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Confirm_Password" HeaderText="Confirm Password" SortExpression="Confirm_Password" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="DOB" HeaderText="DOB" SortExpression="DOB" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Gender" HeaderText="Gender" SortExpression="Gender" />
    </Columns>
    ...
</asp:GridView>
```

With these setup above, the binding on `BoundField` should be working properly without changing field names inside DB.

NB: `...` marks removed sections on code sample for brevity.

Similar issues:

[Incorrect syntax near 'nvarchar' must declare scalar variable near @num](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11801373/incorrect-syntax-near-nvarchar-must-declare-scalar-variable-near-num)

[Incorrect syntax near 'nvarchar'](https://forums.asp.net/t/1094247.aspx?Incorrect%20syntax%20near%20nvarchar%20)

[SqlDataSource/DataField Bug in 2.0](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/4d32f487-f9b9-42b9-ba9a-4cde3ec7735e/sqldatasourcedatafield-bug-in-20-?forum=adodotnetdataproviders) (the conclusion made from this post)